# Android resource link failed

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio but I can't fix this error

```
Android resource linking failed Output:  F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:207: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found. F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:207: error: resource android:attr/font not found. F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:207: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found. error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Jayme\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\29f5b1f09c99c35adb27ad420ff37fc9\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.wakeup.xxx\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an own library module in your project. If the app and library module project is different `targetSdkVersion` or `compileSdkVersion` it will show errors. (Also I have an experience same errors. In my case, the app module's `targetSdkVersion` was 28 and the library was 27.) Or you can try these suggestions.

- Clean and Build
- Clean Caches (Windows - Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart)

Answer (score 0):

> error: resource `android:attr/font` **not found**.
>   `F:\Jayme\AndroidSDK\sdk_demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml`:207:
>   error: resource `android:attr/fontWeight` **not found**

It cannot find `attr/font` nor `attr/fontWeight`. Either remove them when using those or add the items (`font`, `fontWeight`) in `attrs.xml` file in `\res\values\attrs.xml`.